# How to set the image in circle round like my sample interface design

Tags: html, css

This is the sample of my interface design
https://ibb.co/g94jz0f

And this is my code output design
https://ibb.co/k1QwCpt

Hi,
I want to know what is the best way solution to set the image into circle round like my sample interface.

Here are my html source code

```css
body {
  background-image: url('Background_JPEG.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="Cosmetic.png" width="500" height="333">
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <img src="BodyCare.png" width="500" height="333">
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <img src="FacialCare.png" width="500" height="333">
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <img src="HairCare.png" width="500" height="333">
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <img src="MumBabyProduct.png" width="500" height="333">
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <img src="Other.png" width="500" height="333">
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <img src="SPA.png" width="500" height="333">
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try using the same width as height for the img? `width="500" height="500"`

Comment: Yes, I try already but the image becomes vertical. I want all the different bubble image to become round together like my interface design.

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: I changed your code snippets to a stack snippet (like jsfiddle). If you upload your images to for example *imgur* or *ibb* you could add the image urls to that snippet...

Comment: Please update your images here.

Comment: This all is my images link URL     https://ibb.co/yPj19b6
https://ibb.co/FW1dQTX
https://ibb.co/2d0Fw0P
https://ibb.co/CJ0nxJR
https://ibb.co/5G5VnZ2
https://ibb.co/sVmv2DV
https://ibb.co/Xt36CWK
https://ibb.co/KxnjLZh

Comment: @ihimv here my jsfiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/m4cus89/4hwsym7u/2/

Answer (score 1):

you can do something similar to it. and also set position based on class name. As per the design, you need the same height and width of the circle item.

```css
.cosmetic-bg {
     border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}

.cosmetic-bg-1 {
 background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150");
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
}

.cosmetic-bg-2 {
 background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/250");
 height: 250px;
 width: 250px;
}

.cosmetic-bg-2 {
 background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/300");
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cosmetic-bg cosmetic-bg-1"></div>
<div class="cosmetic-bg cosmetic-bg-1"></div>
<div class="cosmetic-bg cosmetic-bg-1"></div>
<div class="cosmetic-bg cosmetic-bg-3"></div>
<div class="cosmetic-bg cosmetic-bg-2"></div>
```

Comment: I will try it later